# remove default styles of headings in google docs

Tags: google-docs

I want to make a table with the 1st column reserved for headings as follows:

[image]

How can I make any title in the **"Concept"** column a heading **WITHOUT** the default styling for headings that breaks the table layout as in the following screenshot?

[image]

I would like a title's appearance to remain the same after being made a heading as a result. I need to achieve this in order to use the **"Outline"** feature of google docs for quickly navigating to headings since my table is expected to be very long and filled with a lot of content in the future.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. It's not clear why you want to use the heading styles in a table cell instead of using other options of applying formatting to those cells. Please start by reviewin the help resources for end-users provided by Google. You can find them by clicking in the Help menu of the Google Docs editor toolbar. Also search this this. Once you have reviewed these analyse the formatting options available. If you still need help show what you tried, share what you found and why it didn't meet your needs.

Comment: Related article from Google Docs Editors Help: [Add and edit tables](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/1696711?hl=en)

Comment: I found the solution: in each heading there is an option like `"Update 'Heading 2' to match"` that matches the styling of a heading to the content